# tastypie post authentication issues

Tags: authorization, tastypie

I'm having trouble with tastypie and posting data to it. I only am able to retrieve a 401 error code.

For clarification, I am able to successfully retrieve data from the tastypie api.

Attached are the code snippets, and maybe someone can help me out get behind this.
Before I get started, a little background: I am using a custom authorization class.

```
    class CustomAuthorization(Authorization):
        def is_authorized(self, request, object=None):
            if request.user.username == 'custom_user':
                return True
            return False
```

Here is the actual resource:

```
    class CustomObjectResource(ModelResource):
        class Meta:
            queryset = CustomObject.objects.all()
            authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
            authorization = CustomAuthorization()
            list_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', ]
            detail_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put']
            include_resource_uri = False
            resource_name = 'customobject'
            always_return_data = True


        def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
            try:
                print "request"
            except:
                raise BadRequest('I couldnt save your information.')
            return True
```

I know the obj_create method is bogus, but it should still be called and do something, or is this already the issue?

The following curl command is used to post the data to the tastypie API.

```
    curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"body": "This will prbbly be my lst post.", "pub_date": "2011-05-22T00:46:38", "slug": "another-post", "title": "Another Post"}' http://local.com:8000/api/v1/customobject/?format=json&username=custom_user&api_key=123456789012345
```

The api_key is correct, but bogus in this case!

As previously mentioned, the get method works but the post just wont work.

Anyone have an idea on how to solve this or have a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

I would try a couple of things to debug this issue.

1) Try adding: `allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put']`

2) Add print statements in the custom_authorization to check if that is causing the problems due to the request.user.username being different.

3) Do (2) in the source of APIKeyAuthentication too.

This should be sufficient for you to debug the issue. 
Remember to **remove** the print statements once youre done!

Best of luck.

Comment: Why not just use logging module properly? It has the ability to actually "print" information, or do anything else depending on the logging configuration (eg. to completely ignore debugging logging when on production environment, but leave higher level of logging intact).

Comment: Sure, thats what i use. But if this person needs to quickly debug without going into setting that up, he can just use print statements

Comment: Thanks for your input. It actually was a little bit more confusing than that. As suggested, I added "put" to the allowed methods, but it still wasn't working. I played around some more with the Authentication and Authorization Layer. I fixed those two and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is COULD be due to a known [issue](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/issues/508). On the background tastypie at the moment converts the POST to PUT and as Nikunj pointed since in  list_allowed_methods you don't have PUT the POST gets blocked too... Not sure there though cause you should get method not allowed in that case. I would suggest debug in the method "is_authorized" and check what is happening there.